# Is it ok to show 'might interest you' on hover-cards?

Tags: hover, tags, tooltips, tagging

I'm trying to decide regarding content of hover-cards. The conflict I'm trying to resolve is whether it's alright to direct to other pages on my site that can interest the viewer, or should I keep it more 'on-topic'.

Example: hover-card of a `tag`. Let's say a movie is tagged `action`. and when you hover it a card appears and offers you to also view `action` movies that were created in your location. And that he might want to check out top10 `action` movies. And that `thrillers` is a related tag, and maybe you'd like to see movies tagged `thrillers`.

Pros: I think this can help discover advanced site functionality.
Cons: Not exactly 'expected' behavior.

What is your take?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your specific example, I would not let users navigate through the hover-cards. Rather, I would use the hover-cards to tease the user of the content that awaits her will she click the tag. The navigation, though, should be restricted to the tag (or any other element).

I estimate this would be a great way for letting people discover new content. If by hovering the user would find something she might like, she only need to press her finger on the click button, since the cursor is already over the tag name. You might think of this solution as a really enhanced, and much more engaging, tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can definitely direct to other pages, but make sure, the user will know, he'll be going to another page. You can use whether _blank, or _self. Usually _blank is a bit better, because the user won't lose the progress, but in your case it will become the part of the progress within movies.

If it's not the expected behavior, try to mark it somehow for the user to be clear, what will happen. I don't see your concept by this short description, but there are always some methods to mark the different behavior. (wiki uses that image for external liks, the text will say something related, etc...)